# passing combobox values between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Fairly simple problem i know its something simple i'm doing wrong but i need another set of eyes to help me out here. I have 2 forms/classes and i want to pass the combobox.selectedtext from form, to a string in form2.

```
public partial class Form1
{
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
private void cboBox2_EditValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cat = cboBox1.SelectedText;
        Form2 fm2 = new Form2();
        fm2.frm2string = cat;

    }
}
    public partial class Form2
{
     public Form2()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
public string frm2string
     {
          get;
          set;
     }
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textEdit1.Text = frm2string;
        }
}
```

Form 3 initialized at the same time as form1.

```
 public partial class Form3
        {
             public Form3()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
             }
        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.Show();
                }
        }
```

Form0 loads Form1 and Form3

```
 public partial class Form0
    {
         public Form0()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }


   private void Form0_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                form1 = new Form1();
                form1.TopLevel = false;
                tabdrives.Controls.Add(form1);
                form1.Show();
                form1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                form3 = new Form3();
                form3.TopLevel = false;
                tabdrives.Controls.Add(form3);
                form3.Show();
                form3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can overload the construction of the Form to have one with parameters.

Comment: what you have isn't ideal, but seems like it should work.  What's wrong?

Comment: @Jonesy im getting null for my variable in `Form2`, while i can see the right value is being entered into `fm2.frm2string` in `Form1`

Comment: You realise that you are newing up a new instance of form2 and not even showing it ? Chances are you are looking at the wrong instance.

Comment: there's something wrong that you're not showing, then

Comment: When are you seeing the `null`? You're never displaying `Form2`.

Comment: In every call to cboBox2_EditValueChanged_1 you are creating another form2. I cannot believe that this is your intention.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck could you elaborate on that, that may be my issue, form 2 doesnt actually load until after this happens in form1, so is that an issue?--- yes i dont mean to be starting a new instance, i guess i need the value saved, so when form2 actually opens it can obtain this comboboxs value.

Comment: When do you want to show form2 ? When are you creating instances of it by doing new Form2() ? Only in cboBox2_EditValueChanged_1 or some place else as well ? If you want only a single instance, then this should happen only once.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck it opens up from a 3rd form, form3, form3 open simultaneously with form1.

Comment: show  that code as well.

Comment: And how is form3 created ? Show that code too.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck that should be about everything. form1 and 3 fill tabs while form2 is a popout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simple need to pass references from the different forms that you want to call from another form. Or depending on how the application works you keep a reference of the form you created. That way you can call in any direction depending on the how the dependency really is.

Example 1 in form1: (form2 is a member of form1)

```
class Form1{

    private Form2 form2;

    void someMethod(){
         form2 = new Form2();
    }

    void someOtherMethod(){
         if (form2!=null) form2.doSomething();
    }
}
```

example 2 :

```
class Form1{

    void someMethod(){
         form2 = new Form2(this);
    }
}    

class Form2{
    private Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1){
         this.form1 = form1;
    }

    void someOtherMethodAgain(){
         form1.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This code is only focussing on passing references of forms to eachother, it is far from complete. 
Depending on the situation you need example 1, example 2 or a combination of both, or even something completely different. But somehow you need to know the dependencies and pass them to the correct forms.

For instance when you create form3, you can easily pass form1. But you have 4 forms already, you need to make a drawing and sketch how each form depends on the others. Then you create your code that reflects this drawing.

Btw you can also consume events of a form, in a different form it does not per se have to happen in the form where the event originates.

Comment: so after passing the referance of form1 into form2, i would be able to access the values in the comboboxes on form1?

Comment: yes that would be possible, if the combobox is public. The default is private I think. You can change it in the designer. If you forget to do this you wont be able to access the combobox and the compiler will say it is not accessible due to its protection level.

Comment: okay this is probably what im looking for then, i just haven't used reference before.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-ideal solution may be to change `frm2string` to a `public static` variable which is set by `Form2` on `Page_Load` (or possibly earlier).

A public static variable is non-ideal because they act as a global.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value from form1 to form2 constructor as shown below.

form1:

```
public partial class Form1
{
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        form2 f2 = new form2(cboBox1.SelectedText);
     }
}
```

form2:

```
public partial class Form2
{
     string ComboBoxSelectTexForm1;

     public Form2(string value)
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         ComboBoxSelectTexForm1 = value; //now you can assign this value anywhere you want.
     }
}
```